# ADF v2 - VSTS integration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm not able to configure the VSTS Account for ADF v2. The login I use to access azure portal and azure data factory v2, do have access to VSTS git repositories. But they are not getting listed in the dropdown. Should I configure something or am I missing something?

1. Do the VSTS account and azure active directory account to author ADF v2 - be the same?
2. Even if they are same why am I not seeing the associated git repositories to configure?

I referred here but couldn't solve https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-visually#authoring-with-vsts-git-integration

[image]

Comment: What're VSTS account in https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me? Try it on a new machine add check the result.